# Large bulk capacitance after LDO for linear power supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitance, linear-regulator

I understand that modern L's need output capacitors with very low ESR and ESL for stability (or data sheet recommended values.) Is there any issue with putting a large amount (>=10000 uF) of bulk electrolytic capacitance in addition to the usual tantalum/ceramic capacitors post-LDO (about 10 LDOs in parallel?)

This would be to feed the output of a 250W 10A linear power supply, with potentials for large amounts of load transients.  My thought is that putting more bulk capacitance after would undoubtably smooth the response and ensure stability during heavy peak loads. Low-frequency DC noise is going to ruin the entire supply so I need absolute low-frequency voltage stability <100 kHz.

Comment: Think of the startup surge current. What happens with the 1F capacitor at the output wants to draw a surge current of 100A on startup through your tiny 1A LDO?

Comment: @DKNguyen I’ll probably add an NTC thermistor to limit inrush, like I will have on the input side pre-rectifier. Also, I *think* the LDO's i'm looking at are internally current limited to 1.5A, but that may be subject to change. Of course, I would also have an appropriate flyback diode to prevent negative bias of the LDO.

Comment: NTC won't work well if the supply is cycled.  i.e. it'll work when you first turn it on, but if the user turns on/off, the NTC is already hot and won't limit like you want.

Comment: @KyleB Ah right, good point. Would probably have to rely on the fact that the LDO is  internally current limited, but would probably be better to find another suitable current limiter. The search continues...

Comment: @FelixJen If the LDO goes into thermal shutdown, which it very well might dropping all the voltage across it to limit the surge current, then it gets locked up in a startup cycle where it shuts down, and while it shut down the cap drains empty, and then the LDO starts back up again and the cycle repeats.

Comment: What is the load? To design a power supply you need to know what the load needs in terms of voltage stability and what kind of current patterns it draws...

Comment: Well, you could switch in a resistance during power on and off, using a relay...

Comment: I would probably charge the capacitors with a constant current and switch it in circuit once it is charged completely. I would also not switch it in at initial power up.

Comment: Choose an LDO which can supply a constant current to the output and/or has unlimited output capacitance stated in the datasheet?

Comment: @bobflux the load is going to an audio amp, so wide current swings are very possible.

Comment: @winny that’s probably going to be the best bet I think. Would probably just need a a lot of properly heatsunk LDOs that can supply enough current without shutting down.

Comment: Is the audio amp class D or class AB? What is its PSRR vs frequency? Do you have a link on the docs/schematics?